# Как и где хранятся данные в localStorage?

Tags: javascript, хранение-данных, localstorage

Насколько я понимаю, localStorage - это просто объект-свойство глобального объекта Window, поэтому интересует собственно механизм хранения данных, как это происходит и где хранятся данные: в каком-то файле, или в некой локальной базе данных? И где их можно найти, минуя консоль браузера?

Comment: зависит от реализации, вы хотите узнать для какого-то конкретного браузера?

Comment: @Grundy да, например, для Хрома?

Comment: судя [по этому ответу](http://superuser.com/questions/507536/where-does-google-chrome-save-localstorage-from-extensions) - sqlite файлики

Comment: Есть еще ответ. Там [несколько браузеров](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored)

Comment: Да, похоже на то, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

мой вольный перевод ответа: [Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612275/4827341)

---

### Firefox

firefox хранит localstorage в файле `webappsstore.sqlite` в каталоге с текущим профилем.

#### Firefox (Windows XP):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Windows login/user name>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox (Windows Vista and above):

```
C:\Users\<Windows login/user name>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

или:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox on linux:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile folder>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox on mac:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

или:

```
~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

---

### Chrome

chrome сохраняет в нескольких файлах внутри каталога `Local Storage`.

#### Chrome on windows:

```
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\
```

#### Chrome on linux:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

#### Chrome on mac:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<Profile>/Local Storage/
```

обычно:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

---

### Internet explorer:

я не очень уверен, но, думаю, примерно так:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStorage
```

---

### Opera

по словам OammieR:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\sessions\autosave.win
```

или по словам Kevin Hakanson:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\pstorage\
```

### источники

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079075/where-does-firefox-store-javascript-html-localstorage
- https://superuser.com/questions/507536/where-does-google-chrome-save-localstorage-from-extensions
- http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory